# Prove that for all $n \ge 2$ there exist finite field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ of dimension $n$.

Tags: extension-field

Intuitively, for every $n \ge 2$ I can find an element $u=a^{1\over{n}}$with $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$: $u^{n}-a=0$. As $u \notin \mathbb{Q}$, then $[\mathbb{Q}(u)/\mathbb{Q}]=n$ which is a finite extension.

Is this reasoing OK?

Edit: I guess I need to prove that the polynomial is actually irreducible using Eisenstein's criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track.  You should justify why you are guaranteed an irreducible polynomial, which is simple: let $f(x) = x^n - p$ for some prime $p$.  Then $f$ is certainly irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion.

From there, if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a field extension of dimension $\deg(f) = n$.

---

I should add that $f(x) = x^n - a$ for any arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ is not necessarily irreducible.  For example, $f(x) = x^n - 1$ will always have a factor of $(x-1)$.

Comment: Alright, so I should restrict $a$ to be a prime number and I can always apply Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: Yep, that is the safest route and it works.